# What is a valid URI for <img> element's src attribute?

Tags: html

What is a valid URI for  element's src attribute?

Off the top of my head:

```
<img src="https://(www.)img-url.com"/>
<img src="http://(www.)img-url.com"/>
<img src="//(www.)img-url.com"/>
<img src="data:image/imageType;base64,z1c2v3..."/>
<img src="/img-url"/>
<img src="img-url"/>
<img src="../img-url"/>
```

Are there any others?

Comment: This could be phrased another way: "What's a valid URL?"

Comment: base64 is technically not a URL, but a URI. I guess the question could be phrased as "What is a valid URI for <img> element's src attribute?".

Comment: https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/img.html -> https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-uri ??